# Why Validator passes wrong request?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

There is method:

```
 public function index(RolesService $customServiceInstance, Request $request)
    {

        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'email.*' => 'required|email',
            'name.*' => 'required|string'
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            dd('wrong request');
            //throw new ValidationException($validator);
        }

     dd('good request');
}
```

I do POST request without body (email[], name[]), why despite this I always get

```
dd('good request');?
```

Why `if ($validator->fails()) {}` is false?

I send `Content-Type: application/json`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`*` is used to check the values in array. But what if that array doesn't even exist? Check the array first and then the values in array. So it would be like

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'email' => 'required|array',
            'email.*' => 'required|email',
            'name' => 'required|array',
            'name.*' => 'required|string'
        ]);
```

Comment: Nice answer, can you specify why is needed to validate the array first?

Comment: @dparoli `*` is used to check the values in array. but what if that array doesn't even exist? so check the array first and then the values in array.

Comment: Thank you now I understand, upvoted, IMHO this explanation should go in the answer for the sake of completeness.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend to use built in validator in the controller itself like this:

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'email' => 'required|email',
    'name' => 'required|name'
]);
```

and you can even surround it with try catch so you can get the exception and handle it in your own way. Or leave it as it is and laravel will redirect you back to the page with a variable which contains the errors of course if the validator fail. you can access like this:

```
@if ($errors->any())
    <div class="alert alert-{{ session('message-status') }} alert-dismissible">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert"><span>×</span></button>
        <ul>
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                    <li>{{ $error }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif
```

Or you can do it in a way which is much more neat and maintainable by using Form-Request:

```
php artisan make:request MyRequest
```

and put all those validations in that form request.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know your request object but i'll try to explain.
asterisk `*` going into inner array objects like this:

```
Request:[
    [...],
    [...],
    [...],
]
```

In your code, laravel searching for

```
Request:[
    email: [
        ***everything inside email
    ],
]
```

If your request is looks like this:

```
Request:[
    email: [
        "test@gmail.com",
        "test2@gmail.com",
        "test3@gmail.com",
        ...,
    ],
]
```

There won't be an problem. Just i need to see what request sending you if you can provide  it then i can help you better.